# Can't extract embedded font

Tags: fonts, beamer

I use visio (on windows) to generate eps file and show it using latex (beamer) in slides. I compile latex to pdf on ubuntu and everything is fine. However, when the pdf slides are shown on windows or mac, following error is thrown. anyway to avoid this?

```
Can't extract the embedded font "GLFPFT + ARIAL". Some characters may not display or print correctly.
```

EDIT: as I check with pdffonts, there is following line:

```
GLFPFT+ARIAL    TrueType(type) yes(emb) yes(sub) yes(uni) ...
```

Comment: Does the pdf look right? What pdf-viewer are you using on Windows and Mac?

Comment: I am using adobe reader X

Comment: Does the first set of instructions (using PDFCreator to make the EPS) at [this link](http://cpbotha.net/2006/09/04/exporting-visio-2003-illustrations-to-eps/) help at all? I wouldn't bother with the OLETeX instructions just yet.

Comment: @Mike this works!

Comment: @Mike: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: Comment turned into answer, as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://cpbotha.net/2006/09/04/exporting-visio-2003-illustrations-to-eps/)'s instructions work in this particular case. In case the page disappears later, here's the summary:

- install [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/).
- In Visio 2003, print your illustration to the PDFCreator, but first remember to click on the “Properties” button on the print dialog, then “Advanced”, “PostScript Options”, set “PostScript Output Option” to “Encapsulated PostScript (EPS)”.
- In the PDFCreator dialog that appears after you’ve clicked on “print”, select “Options” then section “Ghostscript” and UNcheck the “Use Windows fonts” checkbox.
- Save as EPS (and not PDF).